# react-select hide dropdownIndicator and indicatorSeparator after selecting an option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

After selecting an option I need to hide dropdownIndicator and indicatorSeparator.

I tried to apply styles:

```
indicatorSeparator: (base) => ({
  ...base,
  display: "none",
}),
dropdownIndicator: (base) => ({
  ...base,
  display: "none",
}),
```

but cant figure out how to conditionally put them into react-select styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select 
  components={{
    IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
    DropdownIndicator: () => null,
  }}
  style={{
   ...
  }}
/>
```